# JAVA HBase: how to use CellUtil.getRowByte(Cell, int)

Tags: java, methods, hbase

Can someone please help me how to use CellUtil.getRowByte(Cell, int)? I upgraded hbase from 0.94 to 0.99. I used to use cell.getRow() but in hbase 0.99 its already deprecated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use instead the combination of getRowArray(), getRowOffset(), and getRowLength() under the Cell class, e.g.

```
String row = Bytes.toString(c.getRowArray(), c.getRowOffset(), c.getRowLength());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
String row = Bytes.toString(CellUtil.cloneRow(cell));
```